# Integration by Parts confusion

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, self-learning, laplace-transform

I am using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lmj3s4S62fQ&list=PL5750E3CE53DB625A) to learn `Laplace Transform`. The example used is a fairly basic one:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}t.e^{-st}dt
$$
Simple enough, you need to integrate by parts.
So, $u = t$ and $v^\prime = e^{-st}$

So, $u^\prime = 1$. Well, according to the video it is $dt$ and I can not understand why. If I differentiate $t$ w.r.t. $t$ then I get 1.

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: This is just a matter of notation. Many people find it helpful to write $du=dt$ instead of ${du \over dt}=u'=1$. This occurs with all types of substitutions. For example, if $u=t^2, y= \sin x, w=e^{iz}$, then mathematicians commonly write $du=2tdt, dy= \cos xdx$ and $dw=ie^{iz}dz$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $u = t$, then we need $du$, not $\frac{du}{dt}$. $$u = t \implies \dfrac {du}{dt} = 1 \iff du = 1\cdot dt = dt$$

Just as with integration by substitution, when we designate what $u$ will be, we need to know what $du$ is:

$$u = t \implies du = 1\cdot dt = dt$$

Comment: Ah well, he skipped a step then. . . Hi again, it's been a long time. How r u ? Haven't bothered you in chat lately. Will do so shortly :)

Comment: Hello! Yes, I've noticed you haven't been around as much. Good to see you!.

Comment: Yeah, was busy with some programming work. Making some new Android apps :)

Comment: Do you need help with the integral, or are you good now?

Comment: No, am good for now :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the "tricky" notations in calculus within derivatives is ${dy \over dx}$.  In many cases, this term is used as a literal fraction, such that the pieces $dy = y'$ and $dx = x'$ are separable and can be moved throughout an expression in the process of solving it.  So when you write $u = t$ then take the derivative with respect to $t$, you are actually doing this: ${du \over dt} = {dt \over dt} = 1$.  The video is taking the next step and saying that this implies $du = dt$.